# How do I perform a function over multiple columns and rows selected by row characteristics in a data frame?

Tags: r

My data and task:

Each row of data has 3 columns of defining characteristics and 2 columns containing 'predicted' and 'observed' results. I would like to perform a statistical comparison between the predicted and observed values that have the same characteristics.

Here is a sample data set:

```
metadata <- data.frame("sample" = c(rep("x",8),rep("y",8)),
                   "test" = rep(c("a","b"),8),
                   "strain" = rep(c("i","i","j","j"),4),
                   "predicted" = sample(1:10,16,replace=T),
                   "observed" = sample(1:10,16,replace=T))
```

Here is an example of what I've tried using dplyr:

```
metadata %>%
  filter(sample == "x" & test == "a" & strain == "i") %>%
  mutate(RMSE = rmse(predicted,observed))
```

Which produces:

```
  sample test strain predicted observed    RMSE
 1      x    a      i         5        2 2.12132
 2      x    a      i         6        6 2.12132
```

This is the result I'm looking for. But I need it done for each unique combination of sample, test, and strain automatically. (My data set has a lot more than this example).

I think dplyr is the best solution for this after looking around. But I'm open to any solutions. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)

metadata %>%
  group_by(sample, test, strain) %>%
  mutate(RMSE = rmse(predicted, observed))
```

Comment: I'm glad it's so simple! Thank you!